# Any way to get streaming reads from a Database?

Tags: mongodb, web-services, database

Is there someway where if I want to read some data from the database with certain constraints that instead of waiting to get all the results at once, the database can start "streaming" it's results to me.
Think of a large list.
Instead of making users wait for the entire list, I want to start filling is data quickly, even if I only get one row at a time.

I only know of MongoDB with limit(x) and skip(y).

Any way to get the streaming result from any database? I want to know for curiosity, and for a project I'm currently thinking about.

Comment: Sure; you don't specify the language you're using but all of the drivers I know of support streaming of query results.

Comment: In fact streaming from the data files is by default

Answer (score 0):

here's example of python connection to mongodb and getting data line by line

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.blog
col = db.posts

for r in col.find():
    print r
    raw_input("press any key to continue...")
```

Answer (score 0):

All standard MongoDB drivers return a cursor on queries (find() command), which allows your application to stream the documents by using the cursor to pull back the results on demand. I would check out the documentation on cursors for the specific driver that you're planning to use as syntax varies between different programming languages.

There's also a special type of cursor specific for certain streaming use cases. MongoDB has a concept of a "Tailable Cursor," which will stream documents to the client as documents are inserted into a collection (also see AWAIT_DATA option). Note that Tailable cursors only work on "capped collections" as they've been optimized for this special usage. Documentation can be found on the www.mongodb.org site. Below is a link to some code samples for tailable cursors:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/